# Is it possible to start the SUBMIT action via the Input type='file'?

Tags: html, css, forms, post

When I want to upload an image on my website, the user chooses the image from his device via this:
`<input required name='imagee' type="file" accept="image/*">`
But after choosing the image he needs to click on a SUBMITION-Button to start the upload of the Form:
`<button type='submit' class="user_bnt">Submit</button>`
Is it possible to start the SUBMIT action via the Input? So after he selected the image, submit (triggering my form method="POST") will start?

Comment: so add onchange handler and call form submit?

Comment: Please visit the [help], take the [tour] to see what and [ask]. Do some research - [search SO for answers](https://www.google.com/search?q=javascript+submit+when+file+changes+site%3Astackoverflow.com).  If you get stuck, post a [mcve] of your attempt, noting input and expected output using the [\[<>\]](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/358992/ive-been-told-to-create-a-runnable-example-with-stack-snippets-how-do-i-do) snippet editor.

Answer (score 0):

You can use JavaScript for this. Use the `onchange` attribute and run `.submit()` on your form. Your form tag can look like:

```
<form id="yourform">
    <input required name='imagee' type="file" accept="image/*" onchange="document.getElementById('yourform').submit()">
</form>
```